# Extend array in jquery each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

probably it is a very simple question, but I could not find the solution in spite of lot of "googling":

I want to extend an array in a jquery each loop. But after the loop completion the array is empty again. This is my code snippet:

```
var myarr = [];
var sum = 0;
$("#myDomListElement").each(function(i) {
    myarr.push(i);
    sum += sum + 1;
    alert("I have added " + i");
});
```

At the end of this loop the *sum* has a value > 0 depending on the number of loop iterations. But the *myarr* is empty at the end of the loop. If I debug the code I can see that the *myarr* gets larger and larger with each iteration but as soon as the loop is completed the *myarr* is empty again. (The alert shows that the iteration is done).

What is the difference between a primary type and and array, and is there a way to push elements inside an each loop to be used outside the each loop?

Best regards,

Steve

Comment: `but as soon as the loop is completed the myarr is empty again.` what makes you think that?

Comment: your code works as-is. (if the typo'd double quote is removed)

Comment: Your code works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lvvxrjhj/ after fixing the one typo with an extra quote.

Comment: The double-quote was a copy-paste error - not relevant here. But I had cleaned it up too much for better visibility. In reality I used $("#myListParent li .myclass").each... instead of only $("#myDomElement").each... and this is not working. If I use a class as Ziv Weissmann proposed, it works. But why...???

Comment: Ok guys, it seems to have been a problem of my browser. I could not reproduce the problem in fiddle and when the Firebug debugger showed some strange behaviour later on I restarted Firefox, and now everything is working as expected. Sorry, seems to have been my environment. Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem due to using multiple time the same ID,
ID should be unique, only 1 element should have the ID = myDomListElement.

This may cause your array to be empty in the end.

I've change to 'class' usage and it seems to work fine

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8q22tz6z/)

```
var myarr = [];
var sum = 0;
$(".myDomListElement").each(function(i) {
    myarr.push(i);
    sum += sum + 1;
    //alert("I have added " + i);
});

console.log(myarr);
```

Comment: Hello Ziv, thank you for the answer. In fact with a class reference it works, with an id reference it doesn't. But why? At least the loop is iterated one time as the alert shows (without the quotes typo, of course). The sum correct outside the loop, but the myarr not... Hmmm...

Comment: Yes the loop is strangely enough iterate the elements, but eventually breaks down somewhere... don't have explanation for it except that the jQuery selectors must be valid, which in this case, they are not, therefor expect the unexpected ;) also people vote down too fast... :/ I voted up to counter that, but this is a valid question, with a descent text and shouldn't be down voted ...!

Comment: Hello Ziv, after restart of browser everything is working as expected. I assume it was some inconsistency with combination of Firebug and Firefox... Thank you for your support!